how to use undefined on generateStaticParams? Nextjs
There is [locale] part in the url. If it is 'en' the language is en; and if it does not exist the language is tr.
For example:
en/transactions => english
/transactions => turkish

My generate static params fn is like this
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{ locale: "en" }, { locale: undefined }]
}

But this does not create the turkish pages I think. How can I make it so?
This is a segment from the output
Route (app)                                        Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /_not-found                                    894 B          85.9 kB
├ ● /[locale]                                      7.86 kB         147 kB
├   └ /en
├ ● /[locale]/access-controls                      1.23 kB         140 kB
├   └ /en/access-controls

I am using Nextjs 14 with app directory
